# Download raw text from Project Gutenberg in English AND by genre

Tags: project-gutenberg

For research purposes I need to download some books from Project Gutenberg but only with the genre "fiction" and in English language.
I found that I can download all the English books defining also the output type of file with w-get.

Unfortunately I didn't find if it is possible and how to filter by genre. I know that there is also a R package but then I need the ID of each books and it is not the case. I saw also some python packages but it seems that it is not possible to download books by genre.

Any suggestions it would be appreciated.