# How do I download from Gutenberg by genre or subgenre?

Tags: search, project-gutenberg

For a project I'm working on, I need to access all the English fiction in Gutenberg, and then all the horror stories in English fiction on Gutenberg? I see how I download all the txt files in English. But not by genre or subgenre?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [Download raw text from Project Gutenberg in English AND by genre](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117364/354), but, alas, no solution there either.